# How to create input fields from CSV?

Tags: angularjs

I have a CSV on my scope called `fields`. Now I want to create a form from it.

Something along the lines of :

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fields.split(',')">
    <label>
        {{f}}
        <input ng-model="{{f}}"/>
        <div>my input is = {{{{f}}}}</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Obviously the `input` and result statements are wrong. The question is what do I do instead?

### EDIT

The final goal is to get the `my input is` div from the outside. This will allow me to build a "customize your widget" form which is entirely based on user input.

Comment: you should not be interpolating while using ng-model instead use <input ng-model="f">

Comment: I am currently using <input ng:bind="{{f}}"> - read this post, very interesting. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&pli=1#!searchin/angular/markup/angular/48wXpKVYwII/kOTkDhok4bcJ

Comment: turned out the ng-bind was not the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string in the controller, and create an array of fields:

```
var fields = [];
var tokens = string.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    fields.push({name: tokens[i], value: '');
}
$scope.fields = fields;
```

And then in the page:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fields">
    <label>
        {{ f.name }}
        <input ng-model="f.value"/>
        <div>my input is = {{ f.value }}</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The `my input is` will be coming from the outside later on. I will mention that in my question. I have to have it on the scope.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `my input is` shows the value entered in the input field by the user. Please edit your question, and explain what you actually want to achieve. Example input, and example output.

Comment: The div containing the words `my input is` is gonna be from some parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with a directive and $rootScope (which is a bit ugly, however not more ugly than scope.$parent) - but I am still open for better solutions.

'use strict';

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('metaField', function ( $compile , $rootScope ) {
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      restrict: 'A',

        scope:true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          attrs.$observe( 'fieldName',function( value ){
              console.log(["appending",value]);
              var myTemplate =  "<label>" + value + "<input ng-model=\"" + value + "\"/><div>{{" + value + "}}</div></label>"
               element.append( $compile( myTemplate )($rootScope) );
          });
      }
    };
  });
```

This is the directive code and here is how you use it

```
<input ng-model="fieldNames"/>
<div ng-repeat="f in fieldNames.split(',')">
    {{f}}
    <div meta-field field-name="{{f}}"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uZuIau6gbl2Zc5OdJ1tm?p=preview).